# Base64 and HMAC SHA-256 encoding/decoding in Java

Tags: java, base64, sha256, hmac

I am trying to get my GDAX balance, but I think I can't handle the encoding/decoding properly in Java.
The API reference is here: https://docs.gdax.com/#authentication, and the part I'm trying to do is under Accounts -> List Accounts (only have to scroll down a little bit from the above link) to just get the balance.

Here is the code that I have. I can't seem to get it working despite how much searching I've done on Google and here. I keep getting a 400 error from the server, meaning "Bad Request – Invalid request format".

```
    // Decode the secret key
    byte[] decodedSecret;
    try
    {
        decodedSecret = Base64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
    }
    catch (Base64DecodingException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Failed to decode secret key.");
        return null;
    }

    // Make the header parameters
    long timestamp = (new GregorianCalendar()).getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
    String preSign = "" + timestamp + "GET" + BASE_URL + "/accounts";

    byte[] encodedhash;
    try
    {
        Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        try
        {
            sha256_HMAC.init(new SecretKeySpec(decodedSecret, "HmacSHA256"));
        }
        catch (InvalidKeyException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Failed due to invalid key exception.");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        encodedhash = sha256_HMAC.doFinal(preSign.getBytes());
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Failed to make SHA-256 encode because of no such algorithm.");
        return null;
    }

    HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("CB-ACCESS-KEY", API_KEY);
    parameters.put("CB-ACCESS-SIGN", Base64.encode(encodedhash));
    parameters.put("CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", "" + timestamp);
    parameters.put("CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE", PASSPHRASE);

    // Send the request
    String response = sendGet(BASE_URL + "/accounts", parameters);
```

Here is the code I have inside sendGet() as well, in case that is where the problem is. I know it works without parameters, but I don't know if it uses the parameters properly or not since I can't get it to work.

```
    // Set up the connection
    URL url = null;
    try
    {
        url = new URL(urlStr);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
    HttpURLConnection con;
    try
    {
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Returning null because of failure to open connection.");
        return null;
    }
    try
    {
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    }
    catch (ProtocolException ex) {}
    if (parameters != null) // if there are parameters to add to the connection
    {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : parameters.entrySet()) // for each pair in parameters
        {
            try
            {
                con.addRequestProperty(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Failed to add " + pair.getKey() + ".");
            }
        }
    }

    // Get the response
    int responseCode;
    try
    {
        responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder responseBldr = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) // while we have read another line
        {
            responseBldr.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        return responseBldr.toString();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Returning null from network IOException.");
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Do you set Content-type header?

Comment: I was not setting it. Thank you for that. It is still giving me response 400, though. This is what I did to add the content-type:    con.addRequestProperty("Content-type", contentType);

Comment: Also `preSign` probably shouldn't contain `BASE_URL`.

Comment: It looks like you're right about `BASE_URL`, but it's still giving me response 400.

Comment: Maybe with that error 400 you get some text in response body(error description)?

Comment: Response body is just "Bad Request".

Comment: I was wrong about the body. I didn't realize Java has a separate HTTP InputStream for errors. The body was actually saying the timestamp was bad. I have fixed that now by getting the time from the server and using that instead, but now I'm getting an error saying `invalid signature`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working locally. Looks like you're double encoding your signature.

the steps for creating a signature are:

1. create the initial string that forms the basis of the signature
2. decode your secret to get a KeySpec (new SecretKeySpec())
3. init your HMAC with the keyspec (sha256Hmac.init())
4. use the secret to encode the request signature (sha256Hmac.doFinal())
5. base64 encode the result of step 4.

The only error you've made in the above snippet is to then base64 encode it again in your headers.

HTH